# How do i get 7 consecutive dates(dates are different in array) from an array onwards the current date?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

Lets say my current date is 'May 9' , now i wish to get 7 consecutives events(dates) after 'May 9'. Here's my json array sample

```
[{
    "date": "4 Mar",
    "day": "Mon",
    "holiday_name": "bbb"
},
{
    "date": "7 Mar",
    "day": "Thu",
    "holiday_name": "ccc"
},
{
    "date": "8 Mar",
    "day": "Fri",
    "holiday_name": "ddd"
},
{
    "date": "5 Apr",
    "day": "Fri",
    "holiday_name": "eee"
},
{
    "date": "14 Apr",
    "day": "Sun",
    "holiday_name": "fff"
},
{
    "date": "14 Apr",
    "day": "Sun",
    "holiday_name": "gfgg"
},
{
    "date": "24 Apr",
    "day": "Wed",
    "holiday_name": "ttt"
}, ...
//more in the list]
```

I get the current date with this,

`let day = date.getDate();
const monthNames = ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"];
let month = monthNames[date.getMonth()];
let appendDate = day + " " + month;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you can sort the array in ascending order of date. Then use `filter` and get a new array where date is greater or equal to required date. In your case it is `May 9` & in the example below I have considered today's date. After that you can use `slice` to get required number of days. In your case it is 9 but for example I have considered 2

```js
let date = [{
    "date": "3 Mar",
    "day": "Mon",
    "holiday_name": "bbb"
  }, {
    "date": "4 Mar",
    "day": "Mon",
    "holiday_name": "bbb"
  },
  {
    "date": "7 Mar",
    "day": "Thu",
    "holiday_name": "ccc"
  },
  {
    "date": "8 Mar",
    "day": "Fri",
    "holiday_name": "ddd"
  },
  {
    "date": "5 Apr",
    "day": "Fri",
    "holiday_name": "eee"
  },
  {
    "date": "14 Apr",
    "day": "Sun",
    "holiday_name": "fff"
  },
  {
    "date": "14 Apr",
    "day": "Sun",
    "holiday_name": "gfgg"
  },
  {
    "date": "24 Apr",
    "day": "Wed",
    "holiday_name": "ttt"
  }
];

let dt = date.sort(function(a, b) {
  return new Date(a.date) - new Date(b.date)
});

function getConsDate(dat) {
  return dt.filter(function(item) {
    return new Date(item.date) >= new Date(dat)
  }).slice(0, 2)
}

console.log(getConsDate('7 March'))
```

Comment: +1,  @Dipesh Lohani I would suggest doing the filtering first then sorting for better performance with large data. And .sort already mutates the array so no need of new reference or sort a copy of input array